# Why does the 'Raster to vector' conversion give me out lines instead of polygons?

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

I've downloaded the Corine Landcover Raster for Europe and wanted to convert the tiff data into polygons.

But when i use the conversion tool, I'll get lines as output, which is useless for me because i need the data of the polygons.

I'm using QGIS 2.10.1.

Here's the data set. I downloaded the 250x250 raster

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2006-raster-2

Comment: which tool did you use for the conversion?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your question, but your real need : you should download Corine Land cover in an ESRI geodatabase or SQLite format. You'll find your polygonal entities inside ! Job is already done...

[Download Corine Land Cover 2012](http://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc-2012)

[image: CLC download area]

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS 2.16.1-Nødebo, I downloaded the 250m Corine Land Cover file and loaded it into QGIS:

[image: Corine Land Cover]

I then ran the conversion tool from the menubar:

```
Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)
```

and received this:

[image: Converted]

The tiff file was converted to a polygon file which contains a whooping ~4.84 million polygons. Perhaps you used a different tool?